# from ApplicationDbContext to IdentityServiceDbContext

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, asp.net-core-2.0

In ASP.NET Core 1.1 I used ApplicationDbContext for user identity context and for my models data, following [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/337057/should-i-create-dbcontext-for-my-models-or-use-existing-applicationdbcontext).

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }            
    }
```

and in Startup -> Configuration:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Now I'm trying [asp.net core 2 preview](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/preview#windowscmd).

But now we have IdentityServiceDbContext:

```
public class IdentityServiceDbContext : IdentityServiceDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityServiceApplication>
    {
        public IdentityServiceDbContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityServiceDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }            
    }
```

Question is: can I use IdentityServiceDbContext for my data or should I create sepatate dbcontext?

Looks like they moved IdentityServiceDbContext to identity service.

Comment: I have same qeustion, can someone please shed light on this.

Comment: @SamJackSon, I came to conclusion that you need create application dbcontext, not use identityservicedbcontext

Comment: Thanks Alex.
I was trying to hook sqlite but that fails  due to HTTPS endpoint error & cannot proceed at all. The migration files in template are made for sql server & cannot be recreated for sqlite.
We will have to wait lrease version looks like. or atleast preview3-final.